# How to make in javascript that <a> element disappear after you click on link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, when user clicks on Show Comments, div with comments appears. Problem is that Show Comments stays diplayed after you click on it.

```
<html>
    ..
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
    <body>
    ...
    <div class='comments-container' style='display: none;'>
comment 1: ...   
comment 2: ...
</div>
    <a class='show-comments'>Show Comments</a>
    ...
    <script>
    $(".show-comments").click(function(){
    $(".comments-container").slideDown("slow");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make in javascript that  element disappear after you click on link? Something like this:

```
<a class='show-comments' style='display: none;'>Show Comments</a>
```

Or even better, how to make that Show Comments change to Hide Comments and when you click on Hide Comments, comments are hidden (div with comments is set again to dispay: none), and Show Comments appears again.
Maybe that could be created easier with two  elements:

```
<a class='show-comments'>Show Comments</a>
<a class='hide-comments' style='display: none;'>Hide Comments</a>
```

that changes to

```
<a class='show-comments' style='display: none;'>Show Comments</a>
<a class='hide-comments'>Hide Comments</a>
```

If there is a better way to do this with other language than javascript, please feel free to write it.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/?

Comment: Note "Show Comments" and "Hide Comments" do the same in your approach: they toggle the visibility, and the inner link text changes. So you may not need two separate elements, but just a toggler which also takes care of the inner text (if that's easier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-comments").click(function(){
        var oThisLink = jQuery(this);
        oThisLink.toggleClass('someclassname');
        if( oThisLink.hasClass('someclassname') ) {
            oThisLink.text('Hide Comments');
            jQuery(".comments-container").slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
            oThisLink.text('Show Comments');
            jQuery(".comments-container").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you toggle from `.show-comments` to `.hide-comments` the event will not get triggered. But it'll do the trick with a few modifications.

Comment: I toggle "someclassname". This is not "hide-comments". It is only flag to indicate state of link. I am glad to see my text in your answer :)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed, only I don't understand one thing. What should I write instead of someclassname? I left someclassname and it worked. I also tried to change it to something other and it also worked, not matter what I wrote instead of someclassname.

Comment: `someclassname` is any string which will be only indicator of link state. It is not used in any style purpose. You can change it to any long unique string like 'myverylongindicatorword'.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the jQuery in the .ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-comments").click(function(){
        $(".comments-container").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

This should work.

To answer the rest of your question:

You can use the same element as link for both actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-comments").on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeClass().html('Hide Comments').addClass('hide-comments');
        $(".comments-container").slideDown("slow");
    });
    $(".hide-comments").on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeClass().html('Show Comments').addClass('show-comments');
        $(".comments-container").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

Note: I use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach the event handlers to the elements in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post but I just found something really simple to do.

```
<a class='show-comments' onClick="$(this).hide()">Show Comments</a>
```

Hope it help someone like me who was trying to find about it.